# Call functions in module by name in variable

Tags: python, function, module

I want to call different parts from a dict depending on variable.

```
import fruitList

fruit = 'Banana'

if fruitList.fruit['Color'] == "Yellow":
 print "True"
else:
 print "False"
```

But this does not work, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fruit'

I know i could simply do:

```
if fruit == "Banana":
 var = fruitList.Banana
```

But that is what iam trying to get away from since it becomes to static for my purposes.

Comment: `fruit = 'Banana'; getattr(fruitList, fruit)`

Comment: `fruitList` is a module, which is not-a dict and acts a bit differently.